# Kubernetes static ip for pods (instance)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod

i create cluster using `eksct` , now i have 3 nodes ( 3 instances ) , my purpose is to set **static ip** address ( elastic ip ) for instances not manually, if it possible (i mean create elastic ip and then attach to instance).

i have this two `yaml` file
**Loadbalancer.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nlb
  namespace: nlb-sample-app
  labels:
    run: example
  annotations:
     service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: external
     service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-eip-allocations: eipalloc-ip
     service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

and **nginx.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: nlb-sample-app
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      dnsPolicy: Default
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: public.ecr.aws/nginx/nginx:1.20
          ports:
            - name: tcp
              containerPort: 80
```

when i define `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-eip-allocations:` this in loadbalancer.yaml , it's works , when i ping url it's return static ip (elastic ip ) , but my purpose is when i send requests some website , it's must be static ip . is it good way to attach elastic ip per instance ? what happen when instance down and Kubernetes  recreating new one ?
**shortly , purpose is to add my websites's ip in whitelist.**

Comment: I am curious the reasoning behind this. One of the major features of k8s is that you do not need to manage the network layer in this way.

Comment: when deploy something ip change , i know that k8s do not need this but aws need to attach static ip

Comment: is it good way to attach elastic ip manually in aws?

Comment: k8s with the aws-load-balancer controller also handles updating instance IPs in the load balancer configuration. Your end users only talk to the load balancer. As long as the NLB has a static IP, it sounds like your requirements are already met?

Comment: undrestand but when i want to whitelist my ip? it not static , for example when i delete instance and than kubernetes recreating new one ip change

Comment: you think what i do below is enough?

Comment: Your k8s nodes should *not* receive traffic that doesn't originate from the load balancer. Why are you trying to access nodes directly?

Comment: not nodes , i mean pods , for example i have 3 pods when i delete and create new one ip change , need salways static ip when pods update or delete

Comment: Yes, that is k8s design. Traffic routing in k8s happens via k8s services, not directly to pods. A service definition contains a selector which finds running pods with labels matching the selector. When new pods are added/removed k8s automatically updates its routing for the service. Under the hood this all happens via iptables. See [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Sorry, you did not understand the problem :)

Comment: If you mean that I completely didn't understand and you're talking about outbound traffic, that will use the NAT gateway IP addresses, assuming your using a private subnet for your nodes. It's not related to the Load balancer that handles inbound traffic

Comment: exactly , as i already mention my purpose is to whitelist internal ip . ip by which the service runs globally